# Upload Files in Google Drive with windows phone 8 and C#

Tags: windows-phone-8, google-drive-api

I am developing a Windows Phone 8 app.

I Need to Upload selected files to Google drive through My App.

All Samples are Related to .Net but i need some inputs on WP8.

Any Suggestion would be of Great Help?

Comment: the code should be almost the same what have you tried?  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Drive.v2/

Comment: Did you have a look at the `Drive` API! https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#simple

Comment: i Tried above links and installed API too. but it works fine with WP7 Not WP8 or *.1